# Laravel Valet 503 fresh install

Tags: php, laravel

I just followed the guide on Laravel Valet and I'm getting a 503 error for all *.dev sites.

```
php -v
```

returns PHP7.1 correctly installed and

```
sudo nginx -t
```

also returns no errors.

Does anyone have experience with this?

#### Docker

I do have docker installed with a local proxy by Apache2. Can this cause an interference?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A 503 error means that the upstream is not responding. In your case it would be the Nginx. But I doubt out you have configured Nginx as an upstream.

If you don't want to deal with configuring Apache server, then just shutdown the docker instance. Otherwise, configure Nginx to listen on the Docker instance host network. Also update the Apache configuration.

Yeah, it's messy. Just shut Docker down.